# How can I use Infusionsoft API to add user in my application?

Tags: laravel, infusionsoft

I have to add a user to Infusionsoft using Laravel 5.2 framework.I have made a register form and when I click register user must be added on Infusionsoft. How can I do that? And how can I create a free sandbox application? I've made an account but I haven't received any message on my email.

Answer (score 1):

The restriction of Infusionsoft that sandbox applications don't send emails.

If you want to save any data to Infusionsoft, start with reading [API documentation](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/get-started/).

[Infusionsoft PHP SDK](https://github.com/infusionsoft/infusionsoft-php)  provides Laravel support.